# Access JSX components of a functional component React Native

Tags: react-native, react-functional-component

I have two components a functional one and a class one:

```
export default function SimpleTextButton(props) {
  return (
    <View style={generalStyles.buttonPadding}>
      <Button
        title={props.title}
        onPress={props.onPress}
        buttonStyle={{
          borderRadius: 7,
          marginLeft: 50,
          marginRight: 50,
        }}
        titleStyle={{
          color: props.color,
          paddingHorizontal: 20,
          fontSize: 15,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}


class GlobalStyles extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        children: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    };

    passRecursiveStyles = (children) => {
        return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
            if (!React.isValidElement(child)) return child;
            const childProps = mergeDeep(defaultTheme(), child.props);
            childProps.children = this.passRecursiveStyles(child.props.children);
            return React.cloneElement(child, childProps);
        });
    };



    render() {
        const { children } = this.props;
        return <Fragment>{this.passRecursiveStyles(children)}</Fragment>;
    };
}
```

Here because SimpleTextButton is a functional component i cant access Button as a props.children, is there a way to do so ?
Preferably without changing SimpleTextButton function.

I want to be able to add props to every component of my app with only one GlobalStyle in my code, to do so i would need to access component inside functional component like SimpleTextButton

Comment: You haven't used `GlobalStyles` in the `SimpleTextButton `, then it won't be received as a `children`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you should do this change :

- Wrap your `Button` component as a child to `GlobalStyles`
- Make sure you have imported `GlobalStyles` in your functional component

```
export default function SimpleTextButton(props) {
  return (
    <View style={generalStyles.buttonPadding}>
     <GlobalStyles>
      <Button
        title={props.title}
        onPress={props.onPress}
        buttonStyle={{
          borderRadius: 7,
          marginLeft: 50,
          marginRight: 50,
        }}
        titleStyle={{
          color: props.color,
          paddingHorizontal: 20,
          fontSize: 15,
        }}
      />
     </GlobalStyles>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to add props to every component of my app with only one GlobalStyle in my code, to do so i would need to access component inside functional component like SimpleTextButton